# Alteryx Designer 2022.3 - Writing csv on Azure Datalake Gen2 without quote characters

Tags: csv, azure-data-lake, double-quotes, alteryx

using **Azure Data Lake File Output v2.4.0** on **Alteryx Designer 2022.3** I'm trying to write a csv file without quote characters and comma as delimiter, reading from an Excel file; for the delimiter I get the comma as I want, but I'm not able to generate the csv without quote characters because I always get the csv with double quotes. Here are the options setting in the Azure Data Lake Output node

[image]

Below what I get

[image]

and here what I would like to get

[image]

Using Azure Data Lake File Output v2.0.0 on Alteryx Designer 2020.2 I get the csv without quote characters as I want.

Any hint? Thank you in advance.